# InnerJoin not showing any output while it shows output without innerJoin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

so I'm working on an assignment for school and I've run into a bit of an odd issue.

So, essentially what happens is, if I use the code

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database3");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM review
   INNER JOIN admin
   ON review.adminID=admin.adminID
   ORDER BY review.reviewDate DESC LIMIT 3";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

This is the output

[image]

However, when I remove the InnerJoin this is the output:

[image]

```
      $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database3");
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM review
      ORDER BY review.reviewDate DESC LIMIT 3";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
      ?>
```

How would I resolve this?

Comment: There are no matching rows in the admin table. Try LEFT JOIN.

Comment: where is your html generating code?

Comment: I'll try it now, and report back!

Comment: And the error in the second image is because I removed the InnerJoin for the Admin Table.

Comment: I should clarify, the error isn't with the adminFirstName part; the issue is with the InnerJoin not showing everything else. However, when I remove the InnerJoin shows everything but the adminFirstName is an error because I removed the InnerJoin.

Comment: according to @jarlh comment you should not remove `INNER JOIN` but replace it with `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Alex, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your table data or the code that calls the adminFirstName, which I assume is a call to the field within the row returned after the join.

As jarlh said, your first step would be to try a different join to see if there are any matches at all.  If you tried that and got nowhere, it is most likely:

The adminID field on review is not the same structure as the adminID field on the admin table.  Check your table fields ('show create table admin' and same for review).  Are the adminID fields both integers?  Same container size (usually 11 on a auto-increment), both signed or both unsigned?  Both names spelled correctly, Etc.

If they are a match, then check the obvious - are there actually any exact id matches in the two tables?

Comment: Checked spelling, data type and size and everything is identical besides one being auto-increment.

With a Left-Join it shows everything but the adminFirstName with no errors like when the Inner Join is not replaced with a Left Join.

Comment: Try running the SQL directly on the command line - see what it actually returns in the field you need.  If no errors, I suspect its not returning any matches from the admin table, which goes back to my answer above - there may not be any id matches between the two tables.  Do a select id on both tables to just make sure there is indeed a match and that there are no strange characters or something in what should be a numeric field.